# Возможно ли построить додэкаэдр в python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Хочу попробовать построить додэкаэдр в `python` с помощью `matplotlib`. Возможно ли такое?
Если нет, то какие есть ещё варианты?

Comment: https://qastack.ru/codegolf/67576/draw-a-christmas-star-stellated-dodecahedron

Comment: @Jack_oS, ого! Спасибо) Остаётся только перенести на `python3`)

Comment: там есть код для Python 2.7, думаю, на python3 тоже взлетит

Comment: @Jack_oS, видел что он там есть) Но надо бы ещё проверить, а то мало ли